# LLDB replacement of gdbserver

Tags: macos, gdb, lldb

I'm trying to debug a program using IDA Pro on OSX, The instructions given say to use gdbserver, however lldb has replaced gdb on OSX. So what is the equivalent for lldb? (lldbserver if you like)

Comment: I don't see any reason for down vote. +1 because this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

lldb includes a program called "debugserver" that implements a variant of the gdb-remote protocol that gdbserver also implements.  It is in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources
```

It is primarily meant to be used by lldb and not as a general gdb remote protocol server.    I have no idea whether it will work with IDA Pro or not.  Run it with the --help option to see how to use it.